# Gradient boosting how can accuracy increase when we lower the depth of tree?

Tags: decision-trees, ensemble-modeling

What I don't understand about gradient boost is, doesn't lowering height of the tree means we use fewer features in our model?

From my model I get the highest accuracy when the depth is one. Meaning there is just root node at my trees, and uses one feature. How can a model that uses one feature gives such accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it really hard to imagine how tree-based boosting works. I think there are two important components:

1. Boosting can be seen as an [ensemble method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning), so in essence it is not one "small" tree, but many (in fact a huge number of) small trees which learn together.
2. During learning, there is feedback on the learning process ("[adaptive boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost)"). So observations which are "hard to predict", receive a higher weight (more attantion if you like). This allows the ensemble to learn "deeper" than other methods.

The `xgboost` docs come with a nice [introduction on boosted trees](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/model.html).

Chapter 10 of "Elements of Statistical Learning" covers boosting. It is worth a look. Below is the AdaBoost routine as covered by the book.

[image]

There are also [other boosting methods](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.2752.pdf) which do not work with trees. Here is a [simple L2 boosting routine](https://github.com/Bixi81/R-ml/blob/master/l2_boosting.R) implemented in `R`.

Comment: First you have a tree, and you generate better versions of that tree. That's ok until here. What I don't understand is, if you have a depth 1 it means you will use only one feature. And you generate your solution according to that tree. How can one feature give us a result?

Comment: This is the ensemble part as I understand it, but to be honest, I can‘t give you a good answer on that. I still struggle to get the details...

Comment: @J.Smith, "...and you generate _better versions of that tree_" is incorrect: you generate _new_ trees, in addition to the old ones, and the final prediction (in gradient boosting) is the sum of all the trees' contributions.

Comment: @BenReiniger Hello, thank you for correction. What about feature selection? As I know unlike random forests there is no random feature selection. So do we have the same feature for every tree?

Comment: @J.Smith, both random forest and gradient boosting can subset the features to examine (for each tree or each node).

Answer (score 0):

In boosting, a low biased & low variance model is ensembled by additively combining high biased & low variant models. Here, biases are gradually diminished while keeping variances low. Therefore, a tree with a single depth, that is highly biased, isn't an issue because additively errors will be reduced.